# Send multiple personalized emails using gmailr from R

Tags: r, for-loop, email, tidyverse, gmailr

I'm using `gmailr` for work. I've been asked to send a mail to multiple companies requesting their assistance to a study. For that I'm trying to use the `gmailr` and `glue` packages fundamentally.

Here is the code:

```
send <- c("xxx@gmail.com","yyy@hotmail.com")

names <- c('xxx','yyy')

from <- "aaa@gmail.com"

text <- glue("Hi {names}, \n email test")

files <- c("xxx_invitation_letter.pdf","yyy_invitation_letter.pdf")

for (i in names) {
  
  gm_mime() %>% 
    gm_to(send[i]) %>% 
    gm_from(from) %>% 
    gm_subject(paste("Inv. to study")) %>% 
    gm_text_body(glue({text[i]},"no: {[i]}")) %>%
    gm_attach_file(filename = files[i]) %>% 
    gm_send_message()
}
```

The error I get is: "Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.
Error in gmailr_POST(c("messages", "send"), user_id, class = "gmail_message",  :
Gmail API error: 400
Invalid To header"

Perhaps to do this I should try another code or something. The idea is to send personalized emails to all those receivers.

Would appreciate any help.